# Default action when no subscriptions?

Tags: angular

We have a generic HTTP service to wrap some HTTP behaviors. When there is an error, we add the error to a BehaviorSubject.

I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow... show this error only if nothing is subscribed to the Subject.

```
return this.$http.get(url, jsonData).map((res) => res.json().response_data)
  .catch((err) => {
    this._errors.next(err);
});
```

Basically trying to implement a "final" handling of HTTP errors if nothing else is handling it.

Comment: You could pass to `this._errors.next` an object with a `handled` flag initially set to `false`. A subscriber should set this flag to `true` if appropriate. If still `false` after calling `next`, you could show the default error message. Would that work for you?

Comment: That's a simple idea. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object with a `handled` flag to the subscribers, which should set the flag to `true` after handling the error. It the flag is not set after the subscribers have been notified, show the default error message.

```
export class ErrorHandling {
    public handled: boolean = false;
    constructor(public error: any) {
    }
}

return this.$http.get(url, jsonData).map((res) => res.json().response_data)
  .catch((err) => {
    let errorHandling = new ErrorHandling(err);
    this._errors.next(errorHandling);
    if (!errorHandling.handled) {
        // The error was not handled, show default message
        ...
    }
});
```